# Simply Scheme tree depth count

Tags: tree, scheme

I am working on question 18.3 in the Simply Scheme program (questions at bottom of page):
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch18/trees.html
The problem is to write depth, a procedure that returns the number of nodes in the longest branch of a tree. So far I have written:

```
(define (depth-count node)
    (cond ((null? (children node))
     1)
    (else
     (reduce + (depth-count (children node)))))
```

So I have the base case as a 'leaf' node - no children. I want to + 1 for each parent node to a leaf, then compare nodes at the same depth and take the node with the max from each level.
I am expecting to write more cond clauses which will choose one branch (max node) over another. 
I want the recursive case to be a list that I can count...that's where I think I am stuck. 
Am I going about this the right way? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *counting* the number of nodes, not finding the longest branch - which is the same as finding the height of the tree. For that, you want to recursively find the *maximum* depth of the tree for each node. Something like this:

```
(define (depth-count node)
  (cond ((null? (children node)) 1) ; base case: if node is a leaf
        (else                       ; otherwise node has children
         (add1                                          ; add one
          (apply max                                    ; to the maximum of
                 (map depth-count (children node))))))) ; the recursive call
```

For example, if we use the above procedure with the `world-tree` defined in the given link, we obtain this:

```
(depth-count world-tree)
=> 4
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. I had forgotten about apply. Also thinking about counting depth was helpful. Much appreciated.